# Alternatives to Citrix NetScaler?

Tags: ssl, load-balancing, cache, citrix, netscaler

I'm interested in Citrix product NetScaler.
It's an applicance that you put in front of the web-servers.
Features I like is:

- SSL offload an acceleration (good because of performance and that Verisign charges per machine)
- GZIP compression of HTTP traffic
- Caching of static content (images, css, js etc.)
- Load balancing

Are there any similar products with features like these?

Comment: When considering technology solutions, I would encourage to consider what automation around this would look like. Having used Netscaler myself, I know it has a "NITRO" API, which you can use in Python, and there is also Ansible support.... I would quite like to invest some time in a script that just automates a basic "I want a simple site according to our basic recipe". Netscaler is also long-winded in terms of how you express constructs such as rewrite-policies and path-based content-switches. Consider also a pure software solution, as you can more easily take that to the cloud.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Yes, certainly.**

- [F5 BIG-IP](http://www.f5.com/products/big-ip/)
- [Cisco ACE](http://www.cisco.com/en/US/products/ps5719/Products_Sub_Category_Home.html)
- [Foundry (now Brocade) Server Iron](http://www.brocade.com/products-solutions/products/ethernet-switches-routers/application-delivery/index.page)
- [Juniper DX series](http://www.juniper.net/us/en/products-services/end-of-sale/dx3200/) (being discontinued)
- [Zeus ZXTM](http://www.zeus.com/products/zxtm/) (available as software or appliance)

There are also (quite many) cheaper load balancer appliances. Some examples:

- [Coyote Point](http://www.coyotepoint.com/)
- [Barracuda](http://www.barracudanetworks.com/ns/products/balancer_overview.php)
- [KEMP Technologies](http://www.kemptechnologies.com/)

The one thing that stands out in your post is caching. Many load balancers can do some small-scale caching, but it is usually best done by dedicated HTTP caches, installed as software on servers. Examples are [Squid](http://www.squid-cache.org/)  and [Varnish](http://varnish.projects.linpro.no/).

**Read my [previous post here](https://serverfault.com/questions/59953/can-a-hw-loadbalancer-check-on-http-status-codes/60061#60061)**, and find the links at the bottom and follow them.

Answer (score 1):

[Bluecoat Proxy](http://bluecoat.com/products/sg) can do that and a few more.  I have used them in the past as SSL reverse proxy dealing with a few sites and load balencing.

[F5 BIG-IP](http://www.f5.com/products/big-ip/) also does the SSL acceleration and offloading and a lot more, but I have not used their products in years, but when I did they were nice and more then able to do what you need.

Answer (score 1):

Check out A10's offerings. The API is not as strong as F5 and they use TCL for their traffic control scripting, but it's cheaper and faster than F5.